# Doppler effect and different frames

Tags: waves, doppler-effect

The equation of a travelling sine wave is given by $$y=Asin(wt-kx)$$
 On seeing this from a different reference frame,we use galilean transformation,where,in new frame,replacing *x* by *x-vt*,the new equation is,
$$y=Asin(w't-kx)$$
Where$$w'=w+kv$$
So,the frequency gets changed,not wavelength.

- But **DOPPLER EFFECT** says that for a moving observer wavelength of the wave changes.Where lies the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've described is the case when the observer is moving. It's true that in this case, wavelength has no change, but frequency and wavespeed are changed.